# databinding winform entity framework 6 MSDN sample

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

Trying to create a master-child WinForm with entity framework 6.1.3 in VS2015 Community. I followed the Data Developer Center sample (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076) and several other tutorial from Youtube (Julie Lermann, etc.)
Whenever I slide the first DataSource (Category) onto the form (Grid or Detail) every thing is fine. The BindingSources and BindingNavigator seem correct Properties-> DataSource = categoryBindingSource
When I slide the second (child - Products) DataGrid onto the form, I get a grid with only two columns "Count" and "IsReadOnly". The DataSouce here is productsBindingSource.
I spent day looking for an answer! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From this dense description it's impossible to see what you did *exactly*, you probably skipped some steps.

Comment: Thank you for your interest and response. The following is more detail on the subject:

Comment: Application Players and a Games tables in a many to many relationship. 
One WinForm is intended to have the Players (as Details) and a DataGrid with the Games they play, 
I followed the steps of the “Databinding with WinForms article at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx. Same as YouTube by Julia Lerman( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pmct6OmX_8 ). I select the Player DataSource, and drag it on the form. Works perfect; playerBindingSource and playerBindingNavigator are created. I drag the Games field onto the form and the DataGrid has only 2 columns (Count and IsReadOnly)

Comment: I bet you didn't edit the t4 template.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time. The comment section is so limited and does not allow me to relate the whole procedure and add screen shots.

Comment: No I did not. What is there to edit? Well, I added the three changes for the ObservableListSource. But Julia Lerman does not use this and the dragging still works.

Comment: What's there to edit? Well, it's said in the sample. But OK, since this is your first question, look, these questions about tutorials just don't work at StackOverflow. It's *impossible* to check if you followed all the steps. One small mistake or omission can ruin the whole process and since you're probably not aware of this (because that's exactly your problem) you're not going to tell what you forgot. As a rule of the thumb, questions here should be self-contained and not rely on external sources to be clear.

Comment: Thanks Gert. Very frustrating. So much for EntityFramework.

Comment: You can't blame EF for an unanswerable question.